# Self-Signed Certificate with SAML 2.0

Tags: certificate, self-signed, saml-2.0

Is it possible to sign a SAML 2.0 post with a self-signed certificate? I am in charge of implementing a new SSO procedure with a vendor using SAML 2.0 and we trying to determine if we can sign the SAML post with a self-signed certificate or if we need to buy one.

If we can use a self-signed certificate, does the Service Provider need to do any additional steps to verify the signature? We are creating the SAML 2.0 post as the Identity Provider.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I assume you mean signing the Assertion that is returned via POST binding (see [SAML 2.0 Profiles](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf), section 4.1.4.5).  The SAML 2.0 specification mandates it be signed for SSO, but doesn't get into specifics of CA signed vs. self-signed.

Check with your software (both IdP and SP side) to see what is supported - some have limitations in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The SAML spec actually recommends that you use long-lived self-signed certificates. See [this document](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCCollaborate/X.509+Certificates+in+Metadata) for more info

Comment: The document has moved [here](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/X.509+Certificates+in+Metadata) but it's by no means a _SAML spec_

Comment: That's just InCommon documentation that says that their implementation uses Explicit Key Trust Mode. Other implementations may have other recommendations, the explicit trust is just simpler to implement

Comment: That document talks about self signed certs for service providers, the question is about identity providers.